# imagemagick mac os open gif files

Tags: macos, imagemagick

i'm trying to convert a png file to gif with:

```
convert 1.png 1.gif

convert: no decode delegate for this image format `1.png' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/533.
convert: missing an image filename `1.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/2919.
```

and it's not working on my imagemagick installation on OSX as you can se above, I installed it with brew and when running convert it shows the following delegates:

```
$ convert -list configure| grep DELEGATES
DELEGATES      bzlib freetype jpeg jng jp2 png tiff x11 xml zlib
```

On another computer the command works and this are the delegates:

```
$ convert -list configure| grep DELEGATES
DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg freetype jng jpeg lzma png tiff webp xml zlib
```

The missing delegates on the computer that doesnt works are: mpeg, lzma and webp. However I wonder which of those could be required for open a gif file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `decode` (i.e. read) delegate, so it is failing to read the input file rather than to write the output file.

Try:

```
brew rm imagemagick
brew install libpng
brew install imagemagick
```